# How to split a complex sentence string, keeping the delimiter, but not also placing the demiiter where it shouldn't be

Tags: python, string

I came across this snippet on Grepper:

```
line = "<html><head>"
d = ">"
s =  [e+d for e in line.split(d) if e]
print(s)
#Output:
#["<html>", "<head>"]
```

It works fine for the example given.  But if I split a sentence, this snippet will add the delimiter twice:

```
line = "<html><head>"
d = ">"
s =  [e+d for e in line.split(d) if e]
print(s)
#Output:
#['There are two methods:', ' one is to try, the other is to not try.:']
```

so I worked on it and came up with this, which works:

```
d = ","
splitSentences = sentence.split(d)
counter = 0
maxLines = len(splitSentences)
for splitSentence in splitSentences:
    if counter < maxLines - 1:
       paragraphList.append(splitSentence + d)
    else:
       paragraphList.append(splitSentence)
    counter = counter + 1
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in more elegant way.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Please be clear with reproducible examples, as to what you want.  Your second example has the wrong input.  What determines when you do, and when you do *not* want the delimiter appended to the output?  Are you simply trying to break strings at the delimiter?  This looks like a `index` and slice sequence, rather than `split`.

Comment: I will repeat the tour.  And yes...I need to more carefully review before I press the post button.  And yes, I am trying to split the string at the ':" without it being added again at the end of the second string. The index-slice could work.  I will try that.

Comment: I also gave an answer: simply kludge the final string when appropriate.  Glad to hear that it matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s =  [e+d for e in line.split(d) if e]
# If the delimiter is not the last character, then drop it from the last string.
if line[-1] != d:
    s[-1] = s[-1][:-1]
```

IMO, This is more readable than any one-line solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = line.replace("><", ">#<").split("#")
```

It adds a character to the thing you want to split by, and then splits by that character so you don't lose the delimiter. Might want to use a more specific character or multiple characters though so it does't split at a different "#" by accident.